# ckeditor5 gives an error after npm install in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react, ckeditor5-plugin

I'm doing configuration management through Git in a React team project, and I've created CKeditor5.

The problem is twofold.

1. After git pull origin main, npm install, yarn install, nothing has changed in my code, but my CKEditor5 is broken.

Package.json and yarn.lock codes related to CKEditor5 are also unchanged.

2. When I went back to yesterday's git , it worked fine, and I was back to the HEAD version. And after a few minutes, I went back to yesterday, and this time the error occurred. Code hasn't changed! What's the matter? I expected it to be a cache problem, but it doesn't seem to be.

I've tried things like below

1. Clear the cache of npm and yarn.

2. Delete node-modules folder and package.json file and run npm install and yarn install again.

1. If I import it as below, as in the existing code, my ckEditor5 is not visible at all,

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import {Editor as ClassicEditor} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

[image]

2. and if I import it as below, it is visible, but I cannot read the plugins.

(toolbarView-item-unvailable)

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
...
...

const editorConfiguration = {
    toolbar: {items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'fontSize',
...
...

 <CKEditor
      name={option.name}
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={content} 
      onChange={handleCkeditorState}
      onReady={(editor)=>{
        console.log('editor init..', editor);
      }}
      OnBlur={(event, editor)=>{console.log('Blur Editor', editor)}}
      onFucus={(event, editor)=>{
        console.log('Focus Editor', editor)
      }}
      config={editorConfiguration }
    />
...
...
```

[image]

2-1. At this time, if I add the plugin as below, this error occurs. (duplicated-modules)

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize';
...
...

 const editorConfiguration = {
    plugins: [FontSize],
    toolbar: {items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'fontSize',
                'fontFamily',
                'fontColor',
    ...
    ...
<CKEditor
      name={option.name}
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={content} 
      onChange={handleCkeditorState}
      onReady={(editor)=>{
        console.log('editor init..', editor);
      }}
      OnBlur={(event, editor)=>{console.log('Blur Editor', editor)}}
      onFucus={(event, editor)=>{
        console.log('Focus Editor', editor)
      }}
      config={editorConfiguration }
    />
    ...
    ...
```

[image]

3. So if you change the code as below, the editor is not visible again this time.

(TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
```

[image]

P.S ) [index.d.ts]

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

I'm also expecting a build problem, but I can't solve it.

I haven't been able to solve it for days, please help!

[package.json]

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^36.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^36.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^36.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^36.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^36.0.1",

...
 "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "ckeditor5": "^36.0.1",
    "ckeditor5-build-classic-all-plugin": "^16.0.6",
```

[yarn.lock]

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/-/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder-36.0.1.tgz#35cd80bc1aa645c24c410a6fe3aa256d5f36e8aa"
  integrity sha512-kZUvaG0fpGavArn5Yl2eKkCfCelemRfPRVyPerliJUh/6xhDhwT2ds/stI4VyhE2tHRD9ohOywxAEcH2XJUthg==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/-/ckeditor5-alignment-16.0.0.tgz#2496510dae82282e481dbb6199a9f730b33a8348"
  integrity sha512-yf04et0jSZ4Khhzl/t3GXLbsNMTH0qnyvcDDyIXm8Tu4Qec6c6h2xeCWBNp9cz0gab/91bYFtWReKd/swztMtg==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/-/ckeditor5-autoformat-36.0.1.tgz#5add5fc01de366bc024164a34bab8ddf2cc5b8bc"
  integrity sha512-kve+Ergl40L6DzbtvyTMhbwfMZgpl0SJgsAzukQ72OyvJykQywworJ3zt/PgLCJKD+EKN80X9nR8kfBzXRG/vw==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/-/ckeditor5-basic-styles-36.0.1.tgz#847f722be4153b11237df159f9f5c4fc66e39b37"
  integrity sha512-5qbgzsgmJP7lecf78sy6QpqbsF2BLs7WxziMrJUXQytgq4S7o+Q/uqGF/itpkQMBBnLulRFJ8/x055iOBugreQ==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/-/ckeditor5-block-quote-36.0.1.tgz#d5e7549cd46b5e54fd4bf7dac4747212c23c6811"
  integrity sha512-kLvkHGiu5lAnPiUnRUc0M0Nlls179PmcOvX+YIIp62YBYTxG/R6oCC5clnnhodNiDQBEgwbxqoqTKNSkOX0VWw==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/-/ckeditor5-build-classic-36.0.1.tgz#6f4b54720dae494d5a22d8db061a5c541a7ca64e"
  integrity sha512-noBqFM9rzf9WAn5JLqbmKbjarrrLzu0cNDX8LUaYPa/n/AYThL2ul4vy6zmHS7OS+PJLQaH+S/bTFLRflcVl3A==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox/-/ckeditor5-ckbox-36.0.1.tgz#d30e1c248ede6743022f8558666645f5bbcf016b"
  integrity sha512-QzrsGCj84Yd3wDIvFk/e/BJvjeQHhBDxJ/XUfkDw2rhFvJZ9V5Xx08JR+Hsamvc/wd/ES/SlJyDPRjzdfuq/gw==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/-/ckeditor5-ckfinder-36.0.1.tgz#06814040b614a2c56c5b1aec9a63ea1d2d947eed"
  integrity sha512-2qdUHEDmBdyFMeiNSWgE/f1p3Tt9b1uuOsvAt+pXJHET9zT8TlpipbhzN3e9+Vqbiy7tv1ofK/gGGHLGoI25tg==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/-/ckeditor5-clipboard-36.0.1.tgz#96e150756c5b8e2979bdbf9a23987ac7cccb3829"
  integrity sha512-CFh5oO29dUXwsUf/BPM8g5l8MV3hiG27/h6fpC1qRUTAVXDAj43j+cfYYs8MwNi3hv0c/1KyT1bLySqQ/LZctw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.11"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/-/ckeditor5-cloud-services-36.0.1.tgz#b9861e9305edf978cdc2ebee51058c0a229ae07d"
  integrity sha512-o+Xp3mAWISx+LCHeV8wYN1v7ZA0XUtIOXPb6N+6lJcS9fDSdc/B4+0KnpHoDZQThgvs9UoNb6ty2f3H5Den/Bg==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/-/ckeditor5-core-16.0.0.tgz#c9ff37b883ca293ac5998e04a89e2ac613042e09"
  integrity sha512-JKYnoXgfULjfAGRgVmf9/at3gGikfzKwGp4O8RpE3NYGeb/xH6hSgj2mUE9QwqyAY5at1QLnio5ZvU2HiWL4pA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/-/ckeditor5-core-36.0.1.tgz#637c7b340b42166bd52f6e2c2891eba46d057de2"
  integrity sha512-50O+DYXtaf4dMOn+3mGUvfYiE2qsCgVn114WQj7Tj3pZl5w+pAIv/2P+9cBB2Kb7QxgPZqZ7bvsi9wHqIJ6KCw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/-/ckeditor5-easy-image-36.0.1.tgz#c7d3a150a2061926aad1c367896691d5b73d83fd"
  integrity sha512-t74s840xNPaWibgI1YcC/lHcigCY4zUyXzpXhepWe9qw4zfg58H2wK6a0AwBN+yy8mXcotDUmjXkOXgnNkJp0Q==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/-/ckeditor5-editor-classic-36.0.1.tgz#ae7b5659b9312a2487ef2e92363df8ec73215361"
  integrity sha512-/euO79HzgIxILgxbqpGaMxO3f2BSGazljAGTc+aGJQ4bs9YnkxpeCc2wxYXuUzMNev2vVqhaPTvRJzg2Bb2r9w==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/-/ckeditor5-engine-16.0.0.tgz#68d8fabb4fa31541c9870cc94b021c5cb0f72d4f"
  integrity sha512-2p0DT/1B+UyVAwNkkaNaG4wGkrR0TNQuPJ1c5TEMWb9NVk3mhIOJ+6lPVl0ApP3tmMALol+pLmXLX5aht6Ewnw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/-/ckeditor5-engine-36.0.1.tgz#44092d4d42d7974a8bcad0652ece6255a2256a69"
  integrity sha512-Ze2omTguUggwiL9vvLvPk+QpjEBbIOPS1Hi/ROYlsW8QSdnPbSTv+6rCIYThqJMFeonxLZWV5XwbcqpgSAs0MA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/-/ckeditor5-enter-36.0.1.tgz#00a473406e2d310c6d7b76c32483b58233e24f15"
  integrity sha512-FHZ43bltDGFyihfBOTwBOgsS2mMU2ATR9xxFEKlDP+8+P1bq4e0YkC3t4PuwtHIZMvNHiFxqvmFtA2eznGS7sQ==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/-/ckeditor5-essentials-36.0.1.tgz#4b5e6eca13591301b8ac5653766dbb964d729755"
  integrity sha512-f6yEeSA75/hAqK+hZ09LnUj+2PSXFSTHFBzC32WKr+e2qlTx3/mArvwnnQcTj7lo7SuUmctpg7X5DD3/Rcg+HA==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/-/ckeditor5-font-16.0.0.tgz#6cd1982ccfef413caae6f760df42ff558bb5f73a"
  integrity sha512-ZM7ZBew5k06DILQecBJH4Z+pTOomHOTXhKwdIvtwx7MguY2QIJwMI1Zmx+VrnsSo/fAGv1sIhpAvoLYzhlYpTw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/-/ckeditor5-font-36.0.1.tgz#9498b403188580d469a274fd0904fb8f71796ced"
  integrity sha512-mn6nAG9AQ7bC7ywsEf5+pE09yhPSGupttfZ94bzjqTtQAAEahkiD/ympzfypWyJWCkTUlqa0/ZmF22nqcNlTEQ==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/-/ckeditor5-heading-36.0.1.tgz#2fc3b81e8f33789f3a5ccb640ab9cca2345bdf83"
  integrity sha512-elVL6y8kFFB4wCjmVTYsbx5vFoNCsPn9fAJ4/T2tElb9wszs4BsbMjScUNwVomOxuSPy3x6Qt4HG1NFVoh1FKg==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line/-/ckeditor5-horizontal-line-16.0.0.tgz#6f71f45d5a665ed4dbd4bdb92a2cdbf53abe1f6f"
  integrity sha512-8S67caqOMASE4qfgus/ZDiX850yAT87RHxpy2dzXdYXwRMDmkV2GcaS5o12jaR0zu2IoU6RvyOw9NL+yN6Cihg==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget" "^16.0.0"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/-/ckeditor5-image-36.0.1.tgz#82cfb3b3f30d2c9692daec0ca2552159bf287167"
  integrity sha512-HElSvvBXL4kmwtwrAw28oIuJN1gXMr0kOYnR+sLkJGlfeymOQ4RKEqW3vOPMmN6s2RMJVoNkpytPbhzalFn3Sg==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/-/ckeditor5-indent-36.0.1.tgz#82da3df0018f9f8e5645914309a6d39dc46b503d"
  integrity sha512-3E+3UCP9Krr41yP8g5a/QmJEJCChOFWdrLShi0YYODkJlhI/UUJFWVDTx54x1GnnDhXt8HhpOVGHCo14+KuRfA==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/-/ckeditor5-link-36.0.1.tgz#72855ca3a0f6c016b053692ca25bcdb4dfe36ce4"
  integrity sha512-u0E22wCzgAWMlg5BemYAUHws6zausSek+tmI6VmTRibogsUsfso3JnWI0RXNiEd4i2w1wRspvb9S/D8iy7n4fA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/-/ckeditor5-list-36.0.1.tgz#a1b86a32b81a8761e76933910a4d334a5bba121c"
  integrity sha512-v4h5iXCqbOpjaiQRZNp1SExU7BzKfcDU9VUGZpUzFLC0S1JKVO1DAJKMxhqgUCvgGrTOrYHZoGaqNWQZXXwZQg==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/-/ckeditor5-media-embed-36.0.1.tgz#4d90ac7e331969dd39ad3bbb4c7f64bada54fb58"
  integrity sha512-TBl9bh+wBndkHfjjULqTYdYjbwtpO0ug4QTE5PQuAXrfvNeTAGvpYRqnJtLlASzqvUcgc3uBCXI9sO90ZUnFWw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/-/ckeditor5-paragraph-36.0.1.tgz#c3a75e7e4df69f565651d0deb16cbdf785b17cff"
  integrity sha512-NF1PH9WVfY81vkohj6GV1W/u1ogbZnfy60wrDy8Qp3iaFK1LJBsKNz3q1tf0WkBghaX/MUjR9E06l/OrTtaTZw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/-/ckeditor5-paste-from-office-36.0.1.tgz#ece30fb7f49a81865fd24d394c87076d53882711"
  integrity sha512-JG3Ex/0mQ94E6coU16/CpnjikadCLebRLKXKYQyK/Wag7MbkKh8jgzpnZTC4Br4HvpQORfx7eC475BWF927FeQ==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@^5.1.0":
  version "5.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/-/ckeditor5-react-5.1.0.tgz#af747cd6e3e7c4fcdbffcd1f750005ca5b7fbc41"
  integrity sha512-7+okLprneCOD/zXceiONstUjRQtMSnsYiW7C2uODgXpglYDANw9QbAoyA4+M0ZC2Sjxok56YPy46F7uXB+a6mA==
  dependencies:
    prop-types "^15.7.2"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format/-/ckeditor5-remove-format-16.0.0.tgz#e726583a7e8750287ab2f9f4ab434297fbc9962c"
  integrity sha512-cX9eIY2SnvDHOA4Be0mzkZUbHT5dGZ/ybaaErVhU9wXV0NuHe2Gf5WHRy3Sx6fpSqHUtd3r7SRff7Kywap4wog==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"
    eslint-plugin-ckeditor5-rules "^0.0.2"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-select-all@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-select-all/-/ckeditor5-select-all-36.0.1.tgz#ffc105545e7d04f30a38fc5230c2a17861fe9470"
  integrity sha512-8rPxcenTAoqXy1gleZvfsc7VD0IltPFq8R+blD4JL+sSMMDUtKhPuok4TA9h6Yh0nP6LfRK2fBUKIWH3xRPABg==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/-/ckeditor5-table-36.0.1.tgz#8891e3b3701c1da1a9097b11b878adfd27bef926"
  integrity sha512-ishbq3Rp8n7aypswmbqAVWT5W0iYZfAfm6wS+dpSoFqzAPX6ko8+bnoTkq+Wbs1S4+JDaua7QOJw9A1L1cv17A==
  dependencies:
    ckeditor5 "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/-/ckeditor5-typing-36.0.1.tgz#4a38533848986bcb33905ae22068dd575ce1867f"
  integrity sha512-NwXQxNxf/LLANiiteEVaLr1ZzvJd7y6+O5a6x0Tv9Uuheu80aw2Axm3icneODt05G/XT+iJmCHzUYdEiCsHUaw==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/-/ckeditor5-ui-16.0.0.tgz#b656202e407ec1d6aebbdb96568e73dacc771cef"
  integrity sha512-7mwIRajaN9Mf6S5ZkqWAOt/Rqy6GNS3WxhwaayMym7b1XI4oVIrxEKoun3DoKnKp3bTBMcWdQFJfsRvja2X2hA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/-/ckeditor5-ui-36.0.1.tgz#66f660638f73b3e76787eb025dcf23a12cff75f7"
  integrity sha512-wPqAdXUZnEAD3XPvS5vEGU2kxzTQah3wne3B1esdlbJ7dSLZDdx8r1dyKyp3/WCpCT8G+PqGvSUrlnqcy7WI5A==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/-/ckeditor5-undo-36.0.1.tgz#b392c926c34cd5162d08a55e8faebdd4d29c80a0"
  integrity sha512-TBm6TAnur59f5hqlgUZ89NV3cPQw0xqqpSuVMFrvFruPmPiIay2E34Mapb5KRXr83AEPhNN8GAE2YM7HmMqKrQ==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/-/ckeditor5-upload-16.0.0.tgz#361b3cc3a9f3e463f7504ff6f7b355ae175785b4"
  integrity sha512-GjOENKi53TLeV0+zRIuPabMchDTeOMcgTwV4I0VKHrEbPY4YmVbdoz3BO8KpGhA9/KK7se/JR59yHTviPgbFNA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/-/ckeditor5-upload-36.0.1.tgz#4d9d2e59f8d0a2d7eb409e0c9843a2144c82b1f9"
  integrity sha512-932vnvO++SzfZ6EpNkOj6PPKN6vVgn5aW3gu0c1D51cF9KkCFiaMhBDsOzDRVvq/bbnDqUQ9v3j1cNo2UlC8oA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/-/ckeditor5-utils-16.0.0.tgz#9f7851d0271deebe3db3a5f8f1ca1c1ad6cfdcbc"
  integrity sha512-EMrKmVmxfyuttGlbZI0eK7stYigbo2kFCasN0m2apg/Pn4Dwil0pennWuJ964zvZ8te1Pyt33cweQZlYzSqvYQ==
  dependencies:
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/-/ckeditor5-utils-36.0.1.tgz#d7a9943704fa4a492f79f84eda953116ac152b4b"
  integrity sha512-TW/YRb0OQe88IyqRoq2xS02iXOG82NQybzMuFDnGyCaFV0hA/9ysOyWwFpxDLcPDhDgVJZIxuwvFaek9x+uCMA==
  dependencies:
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/-/ckeditor5-widget-16.0.0.tgz#40702bfbf03a2f29ac8813479c549d647863e417"
  integrity sha512-QZMRRJMAZnD3TtrobcwW/6XBQDk9RslIVux08y5YaALNtwKhTNADzB0FljDjANa+BbVQSV/z9AtGpGpSwCSY9w==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^16.0.0"
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget@^36.0.1":
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/-/ckeditor5-widget-36.0.1.tgz#af4c87ce2d5a714ea0f4c1a8a41b631afbd91de0"
  integrity sha512-on92cCRYLWTfwrpnFi5z4FY7NDhY+X+p6yuYStnB9d9jM3FJi3/7y2q9ojr8fSMot4pQsXCiFXzaF6yez+77wA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    lodash-es "^4.17.15"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-word-count@^16.0.0":
  version "16.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-word-count/-/ckeditor5-word-count-16.0.0.tgz#64865a4bed4d42d06ab45153c95e7e1a6994fbc4"
  integrity sha512-3nYuHdFPMe8mRApPbcddnJ+3yL1I8msRqkjs6MK9q+movUF5GmsXqh9cZBEobZ/s1LxXa72GkwQM4K1ESd0EbQ==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^16.0.0"
    lodash-es "^4.17.10"
...
...

ckeditor5-build-classic-all-plugin@^16.0.6:
  version "16.0.6"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ckeditor5-build-classic-all-plugin/-/ckeditor5-build-classic-all-plugin-16.0.6.tgz#bf9d44a9f5958115de0eeed2c0f5696ecf8646da"
  integrity sha512-znAS+ikie6FBzow6wLqpbgPfyPacjDOVQ8cKCFfGIhVlWqgpzK9OuIUGHy5rDa5dFZ0XmOLVH+LIqEUn4R6vpA==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload" "^16.0.0"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-word-count" "^16.0.0"

ckeditor5@^36.0.1:
  version "36.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ckeditor5/-/ckeditor5-36.0.1.tgz#c3fad590f81deb1cd693be7346a827c4f297dc8a"
  integrity sha512-9zKX7WIRKSDviM0s41VvW8JtDiRtNrhwrzYj4XCjGpZyIXsUKttdJYHIP5iP1MdfZU/hCvpgSUn2fmRPxFbg+Q==
  dependencies:
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-select-all" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils" "^36.0.1"
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget" "^36.0.1"
...
...

eslint-plugin-ckeditor5-rules@^0.0.2:
  version "0.0.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint-plugin-ckeditor5-rules/-/eslint-plugin-ckeditor5-rules-0.0.2.tgz#f6325c6d046b41f05423c3a18bb9794b37c80baf"
  integrity sha512-bV8w34pQcn1IyfdW1IEgfKuc1/hkTYpLo1DglRp1v4a2ph03PkMjN7vZ6FDrmu5ImVDJsd9022j5waA//MeyKg==
```

1. Clear the cache of npm and yarn.

2. Delete node-modules folder and package.json file and run npm install and yarn install again.